# Irritating error from removing cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova

```
cordova.js:1297 Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-document-
viewer.SitewaertsDocumentViewer does not exist.
    at addEntry (cordova.js:1297)
    at Object.exports.clobbers (cordova.js:1307)
    at onScriptLoadingComplete (cordova.js:1551)
    at scriptLoadedCallback (cordova.js:1584)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (cordova.js:1538)
```

So the cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-document-viewer" wasn't working so I removed it and I'm using something else instead. But now this error is being thrown constantly, I don't understand why it's trying to use it since I removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova's remove doesn't remove from the platforms requirement files, search for the plugin name from the parent directory to find which files it's still in and remove it from them

Comment: Wow this is such a shit solution, what's worse, when I try to uninstall something different it bloody re-adds stuff I uninstalled weeks ago! I don't know what the hell is wrong with my dev environment but whoever else has this problem I recommend you commit all your files, nuke your dev environment, take a hammer to your hard drive, get a new hard drive, set everything up again, then pull from your svn. It's either that or you'll end up shooting yourself in frustration